# Failed to configure Release Management service user. Error: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: ms-release-management

I have tried to configure release management to work across different servers with untrusted domains using the steps described in the below article.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/12/12/configuring-release-management-to-work-across-untrusted.aspx

But when I tried to configure RM agent with ghost account, it was throwing error mentioned in the title. Please see the error screen attached..!!
[image]

I am searching for a solution for last few days...!!! Experts please help me.

Comment: Are you logged in as the "shadow" or "ghost" account when you run the configuration tool? If not, try that. Also, make sure the URL you're entering for your RM server is well-formed: `http://<Server>:<Port>`. No "/ReleaseManagement/" or any other URL segments.

Comment: @DanielMann thanks for the response..!! url was correct but i logged in as different user while configuring the RM agent.

Comment: Try to log in as the shadow account. I've encountered exactly that issue before when setting up cross-domain authentication using shadow accounts.

Comment: My RM server license got expired. Need to re install the licensed version and try this out. Will update you for sure. Thank you... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally the issue has been resolved by logging in as shadow account. Changed RM server name with IP in MS deployment agent....!!
[image]

Thank you very much @Daniel Mann for the tips you have provided.

Answer (score 1):

write it down as

Correct way:-
http://(server):(port)

Incorrect way:-
http://(server):(port)/ReleaseManagement

Do not write "/ReleaseManagement/" or any other URL segments after .
This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Logging in as the shadow account may not be possible depending on how you setup the service account.  Release Management site uses windows authentication so if you setup your credentials in Credential Manager on the agent server that will work.  Just specify the fully qualified domain name for your Release Management server and your domain credentials for the RM server's domain.